# Dependency Injection with Orleans (Version 1.2.3) not working

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, orleans

I've been messing around for some hours, but I simply can't get DI work with Orleans.

The docs ([Orleans - Depencency Injection](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/Advanced-Concepts/Dependency-Injection.html)) state:

First you have to list the startup type in the server side config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OrleansConfiguration xmlns="urn:orleans">
    <Globals>
        <Startup Type="Services.Implementations.Startup, Services.Implementations" />
```

Then you have to write the startup class which looks like this:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Services.Implementations
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }
```

}

Currently the `ConfigureServices` method does nothing special. Please ignore this.

The problem is that the method is never called.

I'm using Orleans V1.2.3

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: have you tried using the code as config style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is a mistake in the Orleans docs. The `<Startup>` tag must be put into the `<Defaults>` section:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OrleansConfiguration xmlns="urn:orleans">
    <Globals>
        ...
    </Globals>
    <Defaults>
        <Startup Type="Services.Implementations.Startup, Services.Implementations" />
    </Defaults>
</OrleansConfiguration>
```

Then everything works okay.

I'll send a pull request to the Orleans guys to correct this.